# Using SharePoint SPServices

Tags: sharepoint, spservices

How to set values to a multi choice field using SPServices in SharePoint ?

1. This Code worked

   ```
   $().SPServices({
                  operation: "UpdateListItems",
                  async: false,
                  batchCmd: "Update",
                  listName: "Projets",
                  ID: 53,
                  valuepairs: [
                      ["ProjectName", "Project"],
                      ["ProjectType", "OPPS"],
                      ["ConcernedServices", JSON.stringify($('#select-multiple-optgroups').val())],
                      ["Cible", "Résidentiel"],
                      ["DateRFF", "2014-12-31"],
                      ["DateLancementPrevisionnelle", "2014-12-31"],
                      ["DateDeFin", "2014-12-31"],
                      ["Priorite", "PA"],
                      ["Concept", "dfsf"],
                      ["Reference", "FDF"],
                  ],
                  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

      }});
   ```
2. But if I want to add multiple choice doesn't work

   ```
   $().SPServices({
                  operation: "UpdateListItems",
                  async: false,
                  batchCmd: "Update",
                  webURL: "/sites/ep/",
                  listName: "Projets",
                  ID: 53,
                  valuepairs: [
                      ["ProjectName", "Project"],
                      ["ProjectType", "OPPS"],
                      ["ConcernedServices", JSON.stringify($('#select-multiple-optgroups').val())],
                      ["Cible", "Résidentiel, Business"],
                      ["DateRFF", "2014-12-31"],
                      ["DateLancementPrevisionnelle", "2014-12-31"],
                      ["DateDeFin", "2014-12-31"],
                      ["Priorite", "PA"],
                      ["Concept", "dfsf"],
                      ["Reference", "FDF"],
                  ],
                  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

      }});
   ```

Cible is a Multiple Choice field in a sharepoint List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SPServices is calling the OOB webservices behind the scenes, in theory the standard means of updating multiple choice values should come into play: Delimit the values with `;#`

E.g.

```
";#Résidentiel;#Business;#"
```

**Note:** Order matters. Make sure values are specified in the same order they're defined in the column

Comment: I'd also be cautious about passing in accented letters without encoding. I'm unsure whether SPServices handles this but I've been caught out before with Lists.asmx and other native SP services.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post while trying to achieve the same thing, however this answer didn't work for me. I was eventually able to save multiple values in the lookup field using the following format:

```
"6;#;#8;#"
```

Where the numbers are the ID of the list items (to save formatting issues)

With the ID and the title of the list item it looked like this:

```
"6;#Alcohol:Reports;#4;#Alcohol: News"
```

Both of these methods successfully inserted the values into the list.